# Service name not found after Docker Swarm Leave

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have 2 different Ubuntu servers (A and B). On server A, I created 3 containers with service names webserver, app, and database (defined in the same docker-compose.yml file). I created a separate network called laravel_network for these 3 containers using the bridge driver.

When I entered the app container and ran the command "ping database" or "ping the IP of the database container," both worked fine, and the Laravel application ran smoothly. In the .env file, I set DB_HOST=database, and after a month, I checked, and it was still running fine.

Then, on server B, I created a Docker Swarm manager, and on server A, I joined the swarm and verified that the join was successful. After that, on server A, I executed the command "docker swarm leave." At this point, the Laravel application on server A reported that it couldn't connect to the database.

I entered the app container to run the two initial ping commands again. "Ping database" showed an error roughly saying that there was no database service or some network resolution error. However, "ping the IP of the container database" still worked. So, I had to modify the .env file to DB_HOST=ip_container_database to reconnect the application to the database.

When I inspected the database container, the alias network was still "database" as before. I checked the container logs, but there were no errors. So, what could be the issue that after leaving the swarm, I couldn't ping the service name anymore? I have reproduced this error multiple times and searched on Google, but I couldn't find any answers. Thank you very much!